# SQLite Update Called from a programmatically-Added Button not Doing Anything

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm working on an Android app, in which an activity gathers all of the data from the built-in SQLite Database and programmatically generates a 2x[n] table of values. The user is prompted if they want to change a parameter of a specific column when pressing on one of these buttons. For some reason, everything compiles and runs properly (the dialog even dismisses, which I only have happening if the data is properly inserted), but nothing is actually being updated.

Warning, shoddy code ahead as I'm still new to Android dev.

`AllStreaks.java`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_streaks);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.all_streak_table);
    res = db.getAllData();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        //show message
        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
        return;
    }

    allStreaks = this;

    streakArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    int counter = 0;
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        streakArrayList.add(new Streak(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(0)), res.getString(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(4))));
        counter++;
    }

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    btnParams.setMargins(200, 30, 80, 30);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);

    i = 0;
    while (i < counter) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            mTableRow = new TableRow(this);
            mTableLayout.addView(mTableRow);
        }

        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mTableRow.addView(ll);

        final Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("" + streakArrayList.get(i).getDaysKept());
        btn.setId(i);

        if(streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory() == null){
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Health")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_health_bubble));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Mental")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_mental_button));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Personal")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_personal_bubble));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Professional")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_professional_bubble));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Social")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_social_bubble));
        }
        else{
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));
        }

        //btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));

        //btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));
        btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AllStreaks.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_complete_or_view);
                dialog.show();

                final TextView dialogMessage = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.select_complete_or_view);
                final Button yesButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes_completed);
                final Button viewButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.view_streak);
                final Button backButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_complete_or_view);

                yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String passNameString = Integer.toString(btn.getId());
                        String activityName = streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getActivityName();
                        String activityCategory = streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getActivityCategory();
                        String dateStarted = streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getDateStarted();
                        int newNum = (streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getDaysKept()) + 1;

                        boolean isUpdated = db.updateData(passNameString, activityName, activityCategory, dateStarted, newNum);
                        if (isUpdated == true){
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        else{
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(AllStreaks.this, "Data not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }
                    }
                });

                viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        editor.putInt("passName", btn.getId()).commit();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(AllStreaks.this, EnlargedActivity.class);
                        MainActivity.getInstance().finish();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        ll.addView(btn);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityName());
        tv.setId(i);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
        ll.addView(tv);

        i++;
    }

    streakCount = db.getAllData().getCount();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("carter.streakly", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_home_button);

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MainActivity.getInstance().finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(AllStreaks.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //streakCount = db.getAllData().getCount();
}

public void showMessage(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

public static AllStreaks getInstance(){
    return allStreaks;
}
}
```

`DatabaseHelper.java`:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "streaks.db"; // Name of DB
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "streak_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "STREAKNAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "STREAKCATEGORY";
public static final String COL_4 = "DATESTARTED";
public static final String COL_5 = "DAYSKEPT";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,STREAKNAME TEXT,STREAKCATEGORY TEXT,DATESTARTED TEXT,DAYSKEPT INTEGER);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String STREAKNAME, String STREAKCATEGORY, String DATESTARTED, int DAYSKEPT){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, STREAKNAME);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, STREAKCATEGORY);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, DATESTARTED);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, DAYSKEPT);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}

public boolean updateData(String id, String streakName, String streakCategory, String dateStarted, int daysKept){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, streakName);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, streakCategory);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, dateStarted);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, daysKept);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "id = ?", new String[] {id});
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id = ?", new String[] {id});
}
}
```

Comment: Which is it that doesn't work? The insert or the update or both?

Comment: The update. It's worked in other activities throughout my app, so I'm led to believe that the lack of anything happening has to do with the fact that I'm updating SQLite data within a custom dialog within the onclicklistener of a programmatically-added button... lol

Comment: do you see the "Data not Updated" message

Comment: Nope - the activity refreshes and the dialog closes like it does in the if case, it's just for some reason nothing is changing.

Comment: So are you quite sure you are passing in different sets of values?

Comment: I mean I believe so. I'm declaring newNum as the current value + 1 like right above it, unless that's not doing adding 1 properly for some reason I believe it is a different set of values

Comment: why not log it in the update method to make sure??

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the correct row and the correct value I want to update :-/